# Generic export of SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got some SQL code from a coworker that should create a new database and many tables with some content. However, this script comes with some "user-specific" definitions.

For example

```
CREATE DATABASE [mydatabase] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'mydatabase', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydatabase.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'mydatabase_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydatabase_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

As I don't have the required file on my machine, I simply resolved this issue by

```
CREATE DATABASE [mydatabase]
```

Then the following line

```
CREATE USER "abc\def" FOR LOGIN "abc\def" WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

produced this error

```
Windows NT user or group 'abc\def' not found. Check the name again.
```

I haven't fixed this yet, but I'm afraid, there will be more diffuculties, as the SQL code is rather long.

It there any way to export the whole code "generically", so that it will immediately run on every machine?

Comment: Not if you want to create logins for existing users.  The user needs to be valid on the machine before you can add a login.  If you don't need to add logins you can remove all of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. In this case `abc\def` refers to a domain user (or group) called `def` on the `abc` domain. On the other hand, you don't necessarily need the users to have a complete database. In fact, you could argue that it's more important for you to specify your own security rather than rely on an imported set.

Comment: Actually, I just need the tables and the content, in order to operate on them. So I just can delete these particular lines?

Comment: Well provided the SQL script includes data, then yes.